# Is QT broken with macOS Mojave 10.14.6?

Tags: macos, qt

I upgraded macOS to 10.14.6, now the QT screen malfunctions, with old 10.14.5, the geometry I got for one monitor is exactly the same as what Quarz API (l=7200,t=0,r=9120,b=1080), after upgraded to 10.14.6, same hardware, the result from Quartz is the same as above, but the QT got is
(l=7200, t=-180, r=9119, b=899), this monitor is a 1080P one.

```
    auto allScreens = QGuiApplication::screens();
    INFO_LOG( "Total screens: %d", allScreens.count() );
    for ( auto i = 0; i < allScreens.count(); i++ )
    {
        auto thisScreen = allScreens.at( i );
        if ( thisScreen->name() == "MyDisplay" )
        {
            auto rect = thisScreen->geometry();
            m_window->move( rect.x(), rect.y() );
            INFO_LOG(
                    "Found the monitor (x=%d, y=%d, w=%d, h=%d) and put my application window on it",
                    rect.x(),
                    rect.y(),
                    rect.width(),
                    rect.height() );
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: QT version is 5.12

Comment: I've updated to 10.14.6 too, and my external monitor is 1080p as well. QScreen reports the correct geometry of my external monitor in both Qt 5.12.5 and Qt 5.13.1

Comment: That is weird, I guess the problem only happens with virtual monitor, not physical one